# (r-1)'s complement or 9's complement

Tags: theory, switching

I have been trying to figure out whether two numbers wud get the same 9's complement value..
I found a general equation for (r-1)'s complement from a text as : (r^n) - (r^-m) - N 
where r = radix or Base; n= no of digits in the integer part; m= no. of digits in the fractional part and N=Given value..

But when I apply this eqn to find 9's complement of two numbers: 0.473 and 9.473 then I get the same result for both i.e. 0.526
i.e. (10^0) - (10^-3) - 0.473 = 0.526; and
(10^1) - (10^-3) - 9.473 = 0.526

Is there another solution to this since these two numbers cannot yield the same result (it shud be wrong)..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `n` and `m` values in your formula are *not* "no of digits in the integer part" and "no. of digits in the fractional part" in a particular `N` value. These `n` and `m` are some numbers that should be chosen once for all your work with complement numbers and not changed, and which set limits on the numbers you can work with: after you choose some `n` and `m`, you can work only with numbers with at most `n` digits in integer part and at most `m` digits in fractional part.

So for your example if you choose `n=0`, then you can not process 9.473. To be able to process both 0.473 and 9.473, you should choose, for example, `n=1` and `m=3` and get 0.526 and 9.526 as results.